# How do I focus the next next element

Tags: javascript, html

`element.next().focus()` won't work if elements are like:

```
<input name="first" /><br />
<input name="second" /><br />
<input name="third" /><br />
```

But will if they're like

```
<input name="first" />
<input name="second" />
<input name="third" />
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: `<br/>` will be the `next()` element of the input field, so you will need to get the second next element or the next element of type `input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css

```
input{
position:relative; 
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

to vertically set one by one without `<br>` tag then use `.next().focus()`

Answer (score 2):

`element.next()` returns the next DOM sibling, not the next form element. That means that if you have `<br>` next to your `<input>` element, it will return `<br>` where `.focus()` makes no sense.

Thats all.

Comment: Upvoting this explain concept behind `.next()`

Comment: Sorry I didn't know br are counted as elements